# Desenvolvimento JEE e PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jee

Estou acompanhando um curso on-line da Algaworks em JEE com PrimeFaces usando o Eclipse e o Tomcat. Quando inicio a aplicação no Tomcat, dá o seguinte erro:

```
GRAVE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addSystemEventListener(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:942)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:351)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    ... 46 more
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar essa dependência em seu `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: OBRIGADO VOU TENTAR AQUI

Comment: Tenta ae e comente aqui se funcionar :D

Comment: MAN, NÃO FUNCIONOU NÃO

Comment: Está com o mesmo erro? Verifique se biblioteca foi baixada

Comment: ta dando o mesmo erro. e a biblioteca foi baixada sim

Comment: poderia postar o seu web.xml e o seu pom.xml?